# How can i get second variable in gnu make targets

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu

Currently i have this

```
test.%:
        echo $*
```

I want to do something like

```
test.%.%:
        echo $1 && echo $2
```

Is it possible to fo like that

Comment: No, but if you provide a real-world example instead of pseudo code then hopefully we can get to the bottom of your [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have one wildcard per pattern, but you can further process the pattern to extract the information you want.  For your example above, this would work:

```
test.%:
    echo $(basename $*) && echo $(subst .,,$(suffix $*))
```